# How to bound the norm of sum of iid Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability, inequality

$ x_1 , .., x_n$ are iid 0-1 random variables.

$\forall i \in [1,n]\;$ Pr$[x_i=1] = p$.

Given that $n \geq 2,\; p \leq 1/2\;$ and  $\;pn \leq 1$.

$h:= x_1+ x_2 +..+ x_n$.

Show that there is an absolute constant $k$ such that E$[h^2] \leq k$.Pr$[h \neq 0]$.

Answer (score 2):

We need to show that $E[h^2]/\Pr(h\neq 0)$ is bounded. Since $h$ is binomial, $E(h^2)=np [ 1+(n-1)p] \leq np(1+np)$ and $\Pr(h\neq 0)=1-(1-p)^n$. Let $x=np$, we have
$$\frac{E[h^2]}{\Pr(h\neq 0)}\leq \frac{x(1+x)}{1-(1-x/n)^n}$$
Given the conditions, we just have to show that the right-hand side is bounded as a function on $[0,1]$. It is sufficient to study its behavior as $x\to 0$. Then $1-(1-x/n)^n\sim x$. The result follows.

Answer (score 2):

I am merely making *bdx77*'s proof more formal, in case it helps someone.

\begin{aligned} 
Pr[h \neq 0] &= 1 - (1-p)^n \\
&\geq 1-e^{-pn}\; \text{(Since} \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\; (1-x \leq e^{-x}\text{))}\\
&\geq \frac{pn}{2} \;\text{(Since} \; \forall x \in [0,1]\; (e^{-x} \leq 1-\frac{x}{2}\text{))}
\end{aligned}

Now,
\begin{aligned}
E[h^2] &= np + n(n-1)p^2 \\
&\leq np(1+np)\\
&\leq 2np\\
&= 4(\frac{np}{2})\\
&\leq 4Pr[h \neq 0]
\end{aligned}
which is what we set out for.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_i\sim Bernoulli(p)$ are i.i.d. then $H = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim Binomial(n,p)$. You are seeking a bound for the second moment of $H$, which can be calculated explicitly as
$$
E[H^2] = var(H)+E[H]^2 = np(1-p)+(np)^2 = np(1+p(n-1)).
$$
EDIT

Given that $np\leq 1$ and $p$ is at least $0$, we can bound $E[H^2]$ through the inequalities
$$
np\leq 1\\
np+1-p\leq 1+1-p\leq 2
$$
which impies that $E[H^2]\leq 2$. This bound could be improved, however. I am not sure how though.

Comment: Shouldn't $E[H]^2$ be $(np)^2 = n^2 p^2$?

Comment: Also, the inequality obtained is not sufficient, since we require $\Pr(h\neq 0)$ on the right-hand side...

Comment: Edited regarding @MXXZ comment.